# Sum digits of number

Tags: c

Hello i need problem with this task in C language. If anyone had a similar problem it would help me.
The task is:
Write a program that loads the numbers a and b (a <b), then finds and prints the numbers from the segment of [a, b] and prints the sum of the digits of each number.
I wrote for three issues, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   int n1,n2,sum=0,a,b,k,n3;
   scanf("%d",&a);
   scanf("%d",&b);
   for(k=a;k<=b;k++)
   {
        n1=k%10;
        n2=(k/10)%10;
        n3=k/100;
        sum=n1+n2+n3;
        printf("%d\n",sum);
   }


}
```

The problem arises when I enter a larger than three-digit number, how to make for any number, no matter if it is two-digit, three-digit, four-digit ...

Comment: How about writing a *function* calculating sum of digits (not limited by 3), then use it? It will help separating the subtasks.

Comment: Well, you hardcoded a solution for at most three digits. A flexible solution will have to use a loop. (Not that [suming digits](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+sum+of+digits) is a very exotic question here on SO.)

Comment: No, I don't understand how to do that when I have a segment like this and I need to calculate the sum of all the digits of each number individually within that segment.

Answer (score 0):

Well the way you solve this issue depends on the exact requirements. Given that you only have ints here I would use the following though it is by no meand production code

```
int main() {
    int a = whatever;
    int b = whatever;

    char* a_as_s = itoa(a);
    char* b_as_s = itoa(b);

    int sum_of_a = 0;
    int sum_of_b = 0;

    for(int i = 0; a_as_s[i]; i++)
        sum_of_a += atoi(a_as_s[i]);

    for(int i = 0; b_as_s[i]; i++)
        sum_of_b += atoi(b_as_s[i]);
}
```

That should calculate the sum of digits for arbirary lengths - the rest of your code seems fine

Comment: ```atoi()``` expects a pointer to char, not a char.
```itoa()```  needs three arguments, one of them being a valid pointer to a char containing the resulting string.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Ah my bad - didnt have the reference on hand

Answer (score 0):

You've already solved the iterating part so as people have suggested in the comments all you need now is a way to sum the digits of an arbitrary integer. I've modified your solution with my take on the problem. I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant/efficient way to do this, so I'd suggest you also check out the links people have provided in the comments. Anyhow here is my take:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxPowOf10(int num)
{
    int divisor = 1;
    
    for(;;)
    {
        if(num / divisor  == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        divisor *= 10; 
    }
    
    return divisor / 10;
}

int sumOfDigits(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int divisor = maxPowOf10(num); divisor >= 1; divisor /= 10)
    {
        int tmp = num / divisor;
        sum += tmp;
        num -= tmp * divisor;
    }
    
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
   int n1,n2,sum=0,a,b,k,n3;
   printf("Insert a: ");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   printf("Insert b: ");   
   scanf("%d",&b);
   printf("Result\n");
   for(k=a;k<=b;k++)
   {
        sum = sumOfDigits(k);
        printf("number: %d    sum of its digits: %d\n", k, sum);
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

The approach is fairly straightforward. To find the sum of the digits, first you determine what is the largest power of 10 that still features in the number. Once that is found we can just divide by the largest power of 10 and add the result to sum. The trick is that, after that, we have to remove the part of the number that is described by the decimal place we are at. So we don't count it again. Then, you keep repeating the process for ever decreasing powers of 10. In the end you have the complete sum.

To illustrate this on 152 for example:

a)  The largest power of 10 in 152 is 100.

b1) We divide 152 by 100 and get 1. We add 1 to sum. We also decrease the number to 52 (152 - 100)

b2) We divide 52 by 10 and get 5. We add 5 to sum. We decrease the number to 2 (52 - 50).

b3) We divide 2 by 1 and get 2. We add 2 to sum. We decrease the number to 0 (2 - 2).

Point a describes the method maxPowOf10
Point b describes the method sumOfDigits